# how to separate words and special character using stanford tokenize?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, tokenize

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP tool and I need to separate chain as:
"(see functional requirement number 150)."

The result of my code is (in corelabels):
[(see, functional, requirement, number, 150).]

when it should be:
[(,see, functional, requirement, number, 150,),.]

The code segment is:

```
public List<CoreMap> armador(String text){

   Properties props;
   StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;
   props.put("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos");
   props.put("ssplit.eolonly", "true");
   props.put("tokenize.whitespace", "true");

   pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
   Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
   pipeline.annotate(document);
   List<CoreMap> result = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);  

   return result;
}
```

Thank's and sorry my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the property:

```
props.put("tokenize.whitespace", "true");
```

By default, CoreNLP will run Penn Treebank tokenization, which will correctly tokenize out the parentheses. However, the property `tokenize.whitespace` forces CoreNLP to tokenize only on whitespace tokens.

**EDIT** You maybe also should be wary of `props.put("ssplit.eolonly", "true");` -- this will only split sentences on newlines.